# Куда jQuery пишет триггеры?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amd

Допустим, есть зоопарк, где изолировано в рамках AMD работают две версии jQuery, подключенные, как два разных модуля. Если определить триггер в зависимом от одного модуля коде, будет ли он доступен для кода, зависимого от другого модуля?